# Warnings ignored if written in a custom auxiliary file (but not if written in .aux file)

Tags: warnings, documentclass-writing, auxiliary-files

For the class I'm working on, I'd like to display some warnings very early in
the `.log` files.

Writing the corresponding `\ClassWarning` or `\ClassWarningNoLine` commands in:

- the `.aux` file is okay but the drawback is that this file is read at least twice (at the begin and end of the document) so the warnings are duplicated,
- a customized auxiliary file is okay, except that reading this file with
  `\input` (or `\InputIfFileExists`) doesn't work: anything is displayed and my
  question is: why?

Here is a MWE that shows the trouble: the `.log` file contains `Warning from .aux file.` (twice) but doesn't contain `Warning from .foo file.`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}%
\LoadClass{article}
%
\newwrite\foofile
\immediate\openout\foofile=\jobname.foo
%
\write\@auxout{%
  \protect\ClassWarningNoLine{myclass}{%
    Warning from .aux file%
  }%
}%
\write\foofile{%
  \protect\ClassWarningNoLine{myclass}{%
    Warning from .foo file%
  }%
}%
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.foo}{}{}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\ref{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I updated with a test so the aux file only prints once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\immediate\write\foofile{%
  \string\ClassWarningNoLine{myclass}{%
    Warning from .foo file%
  }%
}%
\immediate\closeout\foofile
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.foo}{}{}
```

Comment: In the David's solution (`\immediate\write` plus `\protect\ClassWarningNoLine`), the `.foo` file contains `\protect \protect \begingroup \def \MessageBreak {
(myclass)              }\let \protect \immediate\write \@unused {
Class myclass Warning: Warning from .foo file.
}\endgroup`. In the Herbert's one (`\string` instead of `\protect`)), the `.foo` file contains `\ClassWarningNoLine{myclass}{Warning from .foo file}`. In the `.log` file, both lead to the expected `Class myclass Warning: Warning from .foo file.` but the first one is delayed and not surrounded by empty lines. Why?

Answer (score 4):

For writing to foo you want

```
\immediate\write\foofile{%
```

or the write is delayed (forever in this case).

ah I was just going to add (but Herbert already said it) that you want to close the file as well

For writing to the aux there are various ways of suppressing the second use, eg

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}%
\LoadClass{article}
%
\newwrite\foofile
\immediate\openout\foofile=\jobname.foo
%
\write\@auxout{%
\string\ifx\string\AtEndDocument\string\@firstofone
\string\else
  \protect\ClassWarningNoLine{myclass}{%
    Warning from .aux file%
  }%
\string\fi
}%
\immediate\write\foofile{%
  \protect\ClassWarningNoLine{myclass}{%
    Warning from .foo file%
  }%
}%
\immediate\closeout\foofile
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.foo}{}{}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\ref{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (no completion for David's name), what would you advise to use: a custom auxiliary file or the `.aux` file with the trick that suppresses the second use?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé (no need to use the @ form here I get pinged anyway if you comment on an answer) I can't tell from the description which is better (as I don't know why you are writing the warning to a file to execute at a different time rather than just making the warning) but generally I think people prefer.aux then it's an "expected" file and automated scripts that collect or remove  associated files don't need to be taught a new file extension.

Comment: The reason is the following: the warnings my class will provide are not serious as errors (otherwise, they would be errors ;) but I consider the user should be reminded to solve them. But most of the (La)TeX IDEs  filter the `.log` files in a convenient way by  displaying just the errors, warnings and overfull (h|v)boxes. Also long documents often have a lot of bells (especially overfull boxes that are neglected) and, if not on the top list of the bells displayed, those warnings are likely to be forgotten by the user.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé but if you detect the error while the class is being processed then if you report the errors straight away that will come above any in the aux, and if you detect them in the document but delay until the aux is read at begin document, then the error is not reported at all until next yime latex is run?

Comment: Essentially, the "error" (rather an "important" warning :) will be detected in the document so, indeed, it won't be reported at all until next time latex is run. But that's also the case with warnings like "Rerun to get crossreferences right", isn't it? I plan to display such a message in the second use of the `.aux` file.